# Paypal Item Form Won't Align Center

Tags: php, html, paypal

Hello I have setup a paypal form on my website but cannot the dropdown menu to align in the center like the rest of the content.

http://www.christmascakesforcancerresearch.com.au/cakemail.php

Here is the code for the form. Anyone able to please advise? Have tried `<div align="center">` and `<center>` but nothing is working.

```
<form action='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' method='post' target='_top'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_xclick'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='business' value='petjul@iprimus.com.au'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='lc' value='AUD'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='Christmas Cakes'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='button_subtype' value='services'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='no_note' value='0'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='AUD'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='bn' value='PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest'>");
echo("<table>");
echo("<tr><td><input type='hidden' name='on0' value='Cakes'><span style='text-align:center'>Purchase Order Through Paypal / Credit Card</span></td></tr><tr><td><select name='os0' align='center'>");
echo("<span style='text-align:center'><option value='Star'>Star $15.00 AUD</option></span>");
echo("<span style='text-align:center'><option value='Log'>Log $25.00 AUD</option></span>");
echo("<span style='text-align:center'><option value='Round'>Round $60.00 AUD</option></span>");
echo("</select> </td></tr>");
echo("</table>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='AUD'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='option_select0' value='Star'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='option_amount0' value='15.00'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='option_select1' value='Log'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='option_amount1' value='25.00'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='option_select2' value='Round'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='option_amount2' value='60.00'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='option_index' value='0'>");
echo("<input type='image' src='https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif' border='0' name='submit' alt='PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!'>");
echo("<img alt='' border='0' src='https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif' width='1' height='1'>");
echo("</form>");
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Have solved it. Was missing a style in the css code. Thanks anyway for the help.

```
table { display: table; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; }
th, td { padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #eee; font-weight: 400; text-align: center; }
```